# Reading 2-dimensional table to array

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

I have a simple program that tries to read 2-dimensional data into a heap allocated array of floating-points. The program is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


void read_file(std::ifstream &inFile,  float **arr, unsigned m, unsigned n)
{

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            inFile >> arr[i][j];
            std::cout << arr[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}


int main() {

    const unsigned m = 20;
    const unsigned n = 1660;

    float **A = new float *[m]; // alloc pointers to rows 1,...,m
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < m; row++) A[row] = new float [n]; // alloc columns for each row pointer

    std::ifstream inFile("data.dat");
    read_file(inFile, A, m, n);



    // DEALLOC MEMORY
    for(unsigned row = 0; row < m; row++) delete [] A[row]; // dealloc columns for each row pointer
    delete [] A; // dealloc row pointers


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The data is a table of 0-1 entries (see here: [data](http://pastebin.com/1Qs0MzHc)) which is nicely row orientated and has 20 rows and 1660 columns. I added the printing into the `read_file` function to see what goes wrong and it prints only zeros, but the correct amount at least (20*1660 zeros).

The data seems to be tab delimitered; is that the problem or is my approach completely invalid?

Comment: funny how you include `vector` and you don't use it !

Comment: I started with `vector` but then I tried to get to know the `new` keyword.

Comment: Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I suggest you take a look at it. For a *2D array* use vector of vectors.

Comment: You should check if file exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what may happen if the file doesn't exist.

You should check that the file exists after creating the `inFile` object, for instance like this:

```
std::ifstream inFile("data.dat");
if (!inFile)
{
   std::cerr << "cannot open input" << std::endl;
   return 1;
}
```

If file doesn't exist, `cin` doesn't put data in your array, and there are chances that you get 0 all the way (I had 0 + other strange stuff), so to sum it up *undefined behaviour*

Note that if the file exists, your program works as expected. It would be even better to check the file *after* having read a value to be sure that the file has as many values as expected:

```
for(unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    inFile >> arr[i][j];
    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "file truncated " << i << " " << j << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << arr[i][j];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jean. You were correct, I needed to specify the working directory to my IDE, now it works!